# Can't access HD

Tags: linux, partitioning

I opened Dolphin on MX Linux KDE and this is what I got when I tried to access my drive.

An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error unlocking /dev/sda2: Failed to activate device: File exists

I'm fairly new to Linux, so I really don't know what this means. Plz help.